How to read the structure of objects by the "type" field using spring when starting an APP from application.yml
I want to read the hierarchy of objects from the yml file of the service properties. The hierarchy can be read from the yml file with your hands through the ObjectMapper(YAMLFactory())using @JsonSubTypes, but I would like to do it somehow by means of a spring so that when the context is raised, the properties are already connected.

My project on github

My application.yml
parameters:
   vehicles:
      - type: car
        weight: 1500
        capacity: 4
        fuel: petrol

      - type: bike
        weight: 20
        capacity: 1
        numberOfWheels: 2

      - type: truck
        weight: 10000
        capacity: 1
        typeCargo: wood
        fuel: diesel
        liftingСapacity: 20


Configuration Class
@ConfigurationProperties("parameters")
@ConstructorBinding
class ExampleProperties(
    val vehicles: List<Vehicle>
)


My objects
@JsonTypeInfo(
    use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
    include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY,
    property = "type",
    visible = true
)
@JsonSubTypes(
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Car::class, name = "car"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Bike::class, name = "bike"),
    JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Truck::class, name = "truck")
)
interface Vehicle {
    val type: String
    val weight: Int
    val capacity: Int
}

data class Car(
    override val type: String,
    override val weight: Int,
    override val capacity: Int,
    val fuel: String
) : Vehicle

data class Bike(
    override val type: String,
    override val weight: Int,
    override val capacity: Int,
    val numberOfWheels: Int
) : Vehicle

data class Truck(
    override val type: String,
    override val weight: Int,
    override val capacity: Int,
    val typeCargo: String,
    val fuel: String,
    val liftingCapacity: Int,
) : Vehicle

Now I'm getting this error

Property: parameters.vehicles[0].capacity
Value: "4"
Origin: class path resource [application-vehicles.yml] - 5:19
Reason: The elements [parameters.vehicles[0].capacity,parameters.vehicles[0].fuel,parameters.vehicles[0].type,parameters.vehicles[0].weight,parameters.vehicles[1].....fuel,parameters.vehicles[5].type,parameters.vehicles[5].weight] were left unbound.


It was possible to successfully fill in the configuration using this method
@ConfigurationProperties("parameters")
@ConstructorBinding
class ExampleProperties(
    val vehicles: List<LinkedHashMap<String, Any>> = listOf(),
) {
   val activitiesByType: List<Vehicle> by lazy { initVehicleByType() }

   private fun initVehicleByType(): List<Vehicle> {
        val objectMapper = ObjectMapper().registerModule(KotlinModule())
        val vehicleList: MutableList<Vehicle> = mutableListOf()
        vehicles.forEach {
            vehicleList.add(objectMapper.convertValue(it, Vehicle::class.java))
        }
        return vehicleList
    }
}


The expected result is that the configuration with the class hierarchy is read by spring automatically by the "type" field. Just like it happens when reading JSON when using @JsonSubTypes annotations

Change your expectations. Spring doesn't use Jackson to read the YAML so expecting for Jackson features to work when reading the configuration won't work.

I understand that spring does not use Jackson to read the configuration. Maybe there is another mechanism in spring that allows you to read the YML configuration and correlate it by type?

Read it by yourself, it won't be read during the regular loading of the files.
